# version problem - backward compatibility subversion SVN

Tags: svn, ubuntu, backwards-compatibility

I've got my svn repository in a server running `svn 1.4.2` but I'm using `svn 1.6.5` on Ubuntu 9.10 at home.

I found the svn will be corrupted when two the versions are different (at least in my case), and `svn cleanup` won't do the trick.

### I'm not sure should I install svn 1.4.2 at home as well, or is there any way around it?

Answer (score 4):

You should not have any problems using an SVN 1.6.5 client with a 1.4.2 repository.  The only time you'll have problems is if you use two different SVN **client** versions.

Your working copy will be unusable by a 1.4.2 client once the 1.6.5 client has used it.  That doesn't corrupt SVN though... it only affects the working copy (and it's not "corrupted", just maintained in such a way that the 1.4.2 client does not understand).

Comment: That's mostly correct. Note however that some operations will not work and give strange error messsages (as always with SVN ;-), for example the new merge features available since 1.5 and later. But for "usual" operations, as long as you don't downgrade your client with the same local working copy it should be fine.

Comment: Working copy format changes between significant SVN revs (e.g. 1.5.x to 1.6.x) is not uncommon.  However, the WC format changes are documented in the SVN release notes.

http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html